Is the "C0114:missing-module-docstring" shown because the code does not have docstring?
FYI: Coming back to development due to long time interest in python. No actual development experience.
I've been dabbling on vscode as I am learning to code in python and quite frequently seen the C0114 error and tried to read the doc and this is what I understood.
I just started using docstring (or comments) for most of my code and the error stopped showing itself.
I have seen explanations on how to disable the error and was interested in knowing what exactly would be the reason for the error.
I just wanted to know I'm on the right track with my understanding.
Thanks for engaging!
